# Are there examples of Einstein manifolds with unbounded curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Are there any known examples of Einstein manifolds $(M, g)$ such that $$\sup_{x \in M} \|\text{Rm}(x) \| = \infty$$
I'm looking for these examples because they might provide a counter-example to a problem of mine, but I can't think of any. Obviously such a manifold can't be compact but I haven't been able to think of any concrete example.

Comment: A familiar example from relativity is the [Scharzchild metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric), which is Ricci-flat and has diverging Kretschmann scalar $K=R^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}R_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}$. It may of may not be what you're looking for, though, since it is neither Riemannian not complete.